# Xcode is not respecting a gitignore entry

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I have a file called Authentication.plist in my Xcode project and added it to my .gitignore file. However, I can't stop it from being committed to git automatically when doing so via the xcode source control menu. Is there a more effective way to ensure it doesn't get committed?

[image: Xcode project navigator showing the file staged]

[image: Screenshot of the .gitignore list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use command `git rm --cached Authentication.plist` to untrack the file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Xcode's `git` support sucks. It's probably not even seeing that *.gitignore* file (you didn't say which one it was, global, user level, repo level, etc.). Your best bet is to turn Xcode's `git` support off altogether and use SourceTree or the command line. Or, you can at least *reduce* some of Xcode's automatic behavior:

[image]

Notice that I've *unchecked* "Add and remove files automatically". That will at least help work around *this* kind of annoying behavior.

Comment: The gitignore file is one level above the project. Could that likely be the reason for the issue?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ (But I do not guarantee that Xcode will respect a _.gitignore_ even if it is correctly placed!)